# jQuery find element in variable

Tags: jquery, string, element

I have:

```
var html_data = '<div class="div1">something</div><div id="this_is_it">Hello!</div>';
```

How do I check if the html_data var has div this_is_it ?

Trying to check using

```
if($(html_data).find('#this_is_it').length)
```

but is not working....

Comment: Your string isn't properly quoted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.find()` only searches children of the elements it's given, not the top-level elements. So you need to wrap everything in another `<div>`. Also, you need to fix the quoting problem that causes a syntax error -- if you use double quotes inside the string, use single quotes to delimit it, or vice versa (or escape the quotes).

```js
var html_data = '<div class="div1">something</div><div id="this_is_it">Hello!</div>';
if ($("<div>" + html_data + "</div>").find("#this_is_it").length) {
  console.log("found");
} else {
  console.log("not found");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Showing error on chrome 'VM210:48 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Comment: Sorry, had a typo, missing a `+`.

Answer (score 2):

If you would just like to run a check just use indexOf() .

Example 1 :

```
var html_data = '<div class="div1">something</div><div id="this_is_it">Hello!</div>';

document.write(html_data.indexOf("this_is_it") > 1 ? true : false)
```

**OR**

Example 2:

FYI: Checking if length of this_is_it is greater than 1.

```
if(html_data.indexOf("this_is_it") > 1){

//do something here

}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the use of quotations...

it should be structured like:

```
var html_data = "<div class='div1'>something</div><div id='this_is_it'>Hello!</div>";
```

or if div1 and this_is_it are variables, then:

```
var html_data = "<div class="+div1+">something</div><div id="+this_is_it+">Hello!</div>";
```

Then `if($(html_data).find('#this_is_it').length);` should give you a result... or if variables: `if($(html_data).find('#'+this_is_it).length)`

Also `terpinmd` make a great point in the comments, so for it to work with `find()` it should be inside a wrapper element. He recommends the use of [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), which works great. Thank you terpinmd.

Comment: find only works if there are child elements.  using filter or first is the solution...see my post.

Comment: I couldn't tested, but thought it could guide him in the right direction. That's why I write __should give you a result...__, but then again you are right `$(html_data)` is not a document or complete DOM. good clarification, I'll included in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First as the other posters said your quotations are not right...try this:

```
var html_data = '<div class="div1">something</div><div id="this_is_it">Hello!</div>';
```

Secondly you need to use filter in this case.  [Find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) looks through children elements only where as [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) applies to all the elements.

```
var one = $(html_data).filter ('#this_is_it').length;

var zero = $(html_data).find('#this_is_it').length;
```

Your html structure in this case is flat so use filter (or first).

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
var html_data = '<div class="div1">something</div><div id="this_is_it">Hello!</div>';

if(html_data.indexOf("this_is_it")){
    console.log(true);
}else{
    console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't use find() to a variable on javascript, you may need to put in your html code and then you get it by find()

Comment: jQuery returns an object whose HTML contents come from the variable. Why wouldn't you be able to use `find()` on it?